# Need to console.log the clicked item from list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief explanation:** I need to `console.log(i.match)` the clicked item from list. Please see my `**home.html**` code. This is how list is being created

`home.html`

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content *ngFor="let match of matches ; let i = index">
    <p (click)="spch(i)">{{ match }}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

and relevant code of `home.ts`

```
listen(): void {
    console.log('listen action triggered');
    if (this.isListening) {
      this.speech.stopListening();
      this.toggleListenMode();
      return;
    }

    this.toggleListenMode();
    let _this = this;

    this.speech.startListening()
      .subscribe(matches => {
        _this.zone.run(() => {
          _this.matches = matches;
        })
      }, error => console.error(error));

  }

  toggleListenMode():void {
    this.isListening = this.isListening ? false : true;
    console.log('listening mode is now : ' + this.isListening);
  }

  spch(i)
  {
    alert('speech');
    alert(i.match);
    alert(i.matches);
    alert(i);
    console.log('speech');
    console.log(i.match);

  }
```

`alert(i.match)` is coming undefined, `alert(i.matches)` is also coming undefined, `alert(i)` is showing the index number, but I am not getting the valued of the item clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way. you have declared i as index and it will contain just the index values.
try passing two parameters instead:

```
(click)="spch(i,match)"
```

and in ts:

```
spch(i,match)
  {
    alert(i);
    alert(match);
  }
```